# redirect request doesnt complete after removing session or session.abandon

Tags: asp.net, session, response.redirect

I am facing a peculiar problem in redirecting after `Session.Abandon`, here is the code snippet

```
if (Session["Login"] != null)
            {
                login = (LoginState)Session["Login"];
                if (!RoleValidation.ManagerRoleValidate(login.role_id))
                {
                    Session.Remove("Login");
                    Session.RemoveAll();
                    Session.Abandon();                       
                    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");

                }
            }
```

here if the condition is true it takes ages to redirect ... and actually it doesnt redirect to the page at all as if it seems its stuck somewhere ... have put this section into try catch block it says as

```
Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack
```

I am not sure what's causing it. What is the reason why it's happening?

The complete code snippet is :

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["Login"] != null)
        {
            login = (LoginState)Session["Login"];
            if (!RoleValidation.ManagerRoleValidate(login.role_id))
            {
                Session.Remove("Login");
                Session.RemoveAll();
                Session.Abandon();
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", false);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }


    }
public static Boolean ManagerRoleValidate(String Role_id) 
{
    if (Role_id.Equals("1") || Role_id.Equals("2") || Role_id.Equals("4") || Role_id.Equals("999"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;

    }
}
```

and there are no redirects in the Login.aspx so that it can redirect again and again.

Comment: Is this code is in the master page? Is Login.aspx a master content page ?

Comment: @Sreekumar no its not in master page its in child page

Answer (score 0):

There is another request in the process and in the mean time you want another request. If you add false, `it will terminate the current request` and go to login page.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", false);
```

This problem is caused most often if you add `Response.Redirect` Statement under `Try Catch Block`.

```
try
    {
        Response.Redirect(""~/Login.aspx"); // here you want to redirect, but try catch is still have to complete, It will go in the Exception block
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: @Akhtar i already tried that stil its causing the same. :( its not working :(

Comment: Can you remove the try Catch block and try.

Comment: @Akhtar i removed the try catch block :( its still the same :(

Comment: Can you post complete code block ? I think you have use upper try catch some where

Comment: @Akhtar have posted the complete code snippet .. u can have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the reason might be from Login.aspx also your this portion of code is executing, so this response will redirect to the Login.aspx again and again.

Comment: there are no redirects in the login page at all . so there are no chances that it would redirect to the requested url again and again .

Answer (score 0):

not sure why this caused the trouble . i have replaced the

> session.abandon

with

> session.clear

method which clears all the session . although in global.asax i have written

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
    {
        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-30);
    }

    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx"); 
}
```

after removing  the line

```
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
```

from the above code it should have raised the event session_end inside global.asax but for some reason it took ages to compelte the request . so thats how i solved my problem . if someone can please explain what has happned here and how the above thing solved it . please do reply so that other people can benefit from it